# Change iframe source from link href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change iframe source from `<a>` url. http://jsfiddle.net/YkKu3/

My HTML:

```
<a class='gotothis' href='http://puu.sh/666.png'>this Image</a>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<iframe id="frameimg" src="" width="300" height="300">
</iframe>


        $('button').click( function(event) {
            var clicked = $(this);
            $("#frameimg").attr("src", " .gotothis image is here, help '); // Here the problem
        });
```

Comment: can you put some more light on what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of events mixed up. Correct code that will load the anchor URL into the iframe:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('button').click( function(event) {
        var clicked = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#frameimg").attr("src", $(".gotothis").attr("href"));
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/C7kBE/). (With a cute cat :))

Answer (score 3):

You are using a double quote " to open the string, but a single quote ' to close it. Either use two double quotes, or two single quotes.

```
$("#frameimg").attr("src", " .gotothis image is here, help "); // Here the problem
```

Or if you are referring to the fact that you want to dynamically read the gotothis uri, you should just read out the href attribute from the gotothis element:

```
$("#frameimg").attr("src", $('.gotothis').attr('href')); // Here there is no problem
```

Comment: Indeed. And the fact that all code on the following lines has the "this is a string" syntax highlighting, should be a hint.