# Change default iframe src onclick and retain src after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have the following iframe and thumbnails on a page. How can I use javascript so that whenever a thumbnail is clicked, the data-embed-src becomes the default src for the iframe?

```html
<iframe name="starterVID" id="starterVID" width="870" height="498" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
</li>

<li class="span9">
  <h3>Example</h3>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
      <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="http://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="http://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid0 </a>
    </li>
    <!--      <li class="span3"><a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="https://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid1</a></li>
    -->
    <li class="span3">
      <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="https://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid2</a>
    </li>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span3">
    <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/" alt="">Vid3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="https://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/" href="https://vimeo.com/"><img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" alt="">Vid5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="span3">
    <a class="thumbnail cboxElement" rel="colorbox" data-embed-src="https://goo.gl/"><img src="https://goo.gl/" alt="">Picture</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I had the most success using the following javascript, however since I haven't had much luck with this approach I was thinking of trying a different approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setIframeSource() {
       var theSelect = document.getElementById('choice');
       var theIframe = document.getElementById('starterVID');
       var theUrl;

       theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
       theIframe.src = theUrl;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function loadFrame(val, id){
        localStorage.setItem(val, id);

        if(typeof localStorage.getItem('starterVID') != 'undefined'){
          $('select').val(localStorage.getItem('starterVID'));
        }        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi zxb413, here on SO, you can ask about specific programming problems, not others to provide full working code for you. You need to show your effort and include code that does not work as you want it. As a hint, you will need to remove and add a new iframe with new src every time. Modifying src wont work.

Comment: Hey @marekful, you want me to send you the 3 different files I have for this? I've spent quite a while on it and posted the base code I was using in order to make it easier for anyone else taking a crack at it. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You posted HTML only and seeking javascript functionality.

Comment: better? @marekful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change iframe source from link href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040836/change-iframe-source-from-link-href)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of a `data-attribute`, i believe you should use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

> **`getAttribute()`** returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be `null` or `""` (the empty string);

```js
function setIframeSource(vid) {
  var vid = vid.getAttribute('data-source');
  var theIframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
  theIframe.src = vid;
}
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<p><a data-source="https://youtube.com/embed/t2ByLmLnYJ8" onclick="setIframeSource(this);return false;" href="https://youtube.com/embed/fORZASxZMEQ">Play Iframe video ?</a>
</p><iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289527/change-default-iframe-src-onclick" id="myframe"></iframe>
<p><a data-source="https://youtube.com/embed/fORZASxZMEQ" onclick="setIframeSource(this);return false;" href="https://youtube.com/embed/fORZASxZMEQ">Play astro video ?</a>
</p>
```

About local storage, you should on load, check if there is any data yet to use, else use a default url.

example

```
window.onload = function() {
  var loadvid = localStorage.getItem("test");
  if (loadvid) {//if anything retrieved
    setIframeSource('', loadvid);
  } else {// if empty yet
    var theIframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var defaultUrl = theIframe.getAttribute('data-src');
    theIframe.src = defaultUrl;
  }
};
function setIframeSource(vid, video) {
  if (!video) {// if not from onload or empty yet
    var video = vid.getAttribute("data-source");
  }
  var theIframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
  video = video.replace(/"/g, '');
  theIframe.src = video;
  if (vid) {// if from onclick , then store it
    localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(video));
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yzOVEL

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, but I forgot to mention that I needed to retain the src even after the page is refreshed.

Comment: @zxb413 So what was it that did not work ?  catch the data-attribute value or localstorage part ? Cause from your script `theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value` won't work much as it is.  Then where is it that you search video to assign in your localstorage ? ... Please clarify your question and where you fail if those bits of code are not copy/past from elsewhere ;)

Comment: Your code worked fine, I just need to retain the change on page refresh

Comment: @zxb413 What have you tried so far ? this piece of code is just a sample about getattribute()