# how to refresh a src of an iframe within a modal

Tags: javascript, css, html, modal-dialog

I have an iframe within a model . The iframe opens a website eg.xxx . From xxx.com I have multiple buttons on click of a button I am taken over to eg.xxx/yyy.html . When I close the dialog box it still shows xxx/yyy.html and not xxx.com . 
How do I over come this problem with Javascript?

Section Modal Code :

```
<!-- Start Feature Section -->
<div class="section-modal modal fade" id="magazine-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal " data-dismiss="modal">
            <a href="../twt/index.html" style="color: #000000; font-size: 30px;" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- <div class="lr">
                 <div class="rl">
                 </div>
             </div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-title text-center">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row modal-body">
                <iframe src="https://www.pvrcinemas.com/magazines" target="_self" style="position:fixed; top:65px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:95%;color:#000000; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
                    Your browser doesn't support iframes
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Feature Section -->
```

Please help me with the same.

Comment: partially similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289527/change-default-iframe-src-onclick-and-retain-src-after-page-refresh/46290093#46290093 where refreshing scr attribute is done via javascript. if you add an id to your iframe, it will make it much easier to target that frame . The post link also keep in memory a choice done via localstorage ... maybe that was your next question ?

Answer (score 1):

Before calling modal show. Just set iframe src with your required url.

```
$('#magazine-modal').find("iframe").attr("src","https://www.pvrcinemas.com/magazines");
$('#magazine-modal').modal('show');
```